# Finding explicit formula for the following sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I find an explicit formula for:
$T(0)=1, T(n+1)=T(n)*2+4$ ? Or anything of a similar form?

Is there a general way to find explicit formulas for all sequences that aren't arithmetic or geometric?

Comment: $a_n=T(n)+4 ,\ a_{n+1}=2a_n$ geometric series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u(n)=T(n)+4$. Then we have
$$
u(0)=T(0)+1=5,
$$
$$
u(n+1)=T(n+1)+4=2T(n)+8=2(T(n)+4)=2u(n)=2^{n+1}u(0)=5*2^{n+1}.
$$
Hence
$$
T(n)=5*2^{n}-4.
$$
**P.S.** Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation for your last question.